# Extreme values of Enhanced Vegetation Index (EVI)

Tags: google-earth-engine, evi

I am looking to calculate a number of vegetation indices for use in a time series across Landsat sensors. I used the function below to map the formulas across the Landsat 7 and 8 Collection 2 Level 2 Tier 1 Surface Reflectance image collections in Earth Engine and exported the data as a CSV. The NDVI, mNDWI, and MSAVI values all make sense (they are all between -1 and 1), but the EVI values range from -200 to 5000. Can anyone identify what is causing the EVI values to be so much more extreme? I think it might be a scaling problem since I use an expression in the function, but I'm not sure since I do something similar for the MSAVI and don't get any outlandish values.

```
    // Define function for adding vegetation indices
function vegIndex(image) {
  // normalized difference vegetation index
   var ndvi = image.normalizedDifference(['NIR', 'Red']).rename('NDVI');
   // enhanced vegetation index
   var evi = image.expression(
    '2.5 * ((NIR - RED) / (NIR + (6 * RED) - (7.5 * BLUE) + 1))', {
      'NIR': image.select('NIR'),
      'RED': image.select('Red'),
      'BLUE': image.select('Blue')}).rename('EVI');
   // modified soil adjusted vegetation index 2
   var msavi = image.expression(
  '(2 * NIR + 1 - sqrt(pow((2 * NIR + 1), 2) - 8 * (NIR - RED)) ) / 2',  {
    'NIR': image.select('NIR'), 
    'RED': image.select('Red')
  }).rename('MSAVI');
  // modified normalized difference water index
   var mndwi = image.normalizedDifference(['Green', 'SWIR1']).rename('mNDWI');
   return image.addBands([ndvi, evi, msavi, mndwi]);
}
```

Comment: This USGS site suggests valid EVI ranges calculated with the formula as yous quote it are -10,000 to 10,000. https://www.usgs.gov/core-science-systems/nli/landsat/landsat-enhanced-vegetation-index?qt-science_support_page_related_con=0#qt-science_support_page_related_con

Comment: @LeighBettenay that is good to know, thank you! Two follow-up questions: when it says the scale factor is 0.0001, does that mean I should multiply my values by 0.0001? Second, I am still a bit confused because the USGS site has a similar page for MSAVI, and it says that the valid range is -10,000 to 10,000, but the values I got are constrained between -1 and 1. Any thoughts about that? https://www.usgs.gov/core-science-systems/nli/landsat/landsat-modified-soil-adjusted-vegetation-index